# Python animation strange behavior

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am doing an animation of a launched projectile and running into some odd behavior that I don't understand.  I am plotting the animation of a point, representing the object, and also animating the path so that the trajectory shows up behind the object.  However, when I do this the way I think I am supposed to do it, the point is shown one step ahead of the trajectory and the trajectory ends up one point shy of finishing.  I can work around this by increasing the index number of the trajectory, but then it seems like the index should be out of bounds at the end.  I am really confused and could use some help understanding what's going on.

I am working in a Jupyter notebook and have provided a minimally working example below.  I am currently just using 10 points in my linspace command and have slowed down the animation a lot so you can see what's happening.  If I use the command `line1.set_data(x[0:frames+1], y[0:frames+1])` along with `point1.set_data(x[frames], y[frames])` in the animate function, then everything looks fine.  But that seems like it shouldn't work!

What am I missing?

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

# Global constants
g = 9.8  # gravitational field strength in m/s^2
v0 = 40.0  # initial speed in m/s
theta = 30.0  # Launch angle in degrees

# determine trajectory
theta_rad = np.pi*theta/180
t = np.linspace(0, 2*v0*np.sin(theta_rad)/g, 10)
x = v0*np.cos(theta_rad)*t
y = v0*t*np.sin(theta_rad) - g*t**2/2

# Plot the results
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)
line1, = ax1.plot(x[0:1], y[0:1], 'b-', label='no drag')
point1, = ax1.plot(x[0], y[0], 'bo', ms=3)

ax1.set_xlim(0, 170)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 50)
plt.show()

# Animation update function
def animate(frames):
    line1.set_data(x[0:frames], y[0:frames])
    point1.set_data(x[frames], y[frames])
    return

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, animate, frames=len(t), interval=1000, blit=True, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python the syntax `x[0:frames]` defines a range from 0 inclusive up to `frames` **exclusive**.

So, consider the loop:

- At iteration 0 you are updating the point to `x[0], y[0]` and the line plot is empty: `x[0:0], y[0:0]` are empty sets;
- At iteration 1 you have updated the point to `x[1], y[1]` and the line only has one couple of coordinates: `x[0:1], y[0:1]`, not enough to form a line;
- At iteration 2 the point is at its third position `x[2], y[2]` but the line plot lags behind because `x[0:2], y[0:2]` contain enough coordinates for two points, namely the first and second point, enough to only form the first segment but not the second required to reach the point.

Comment: Oh my goodness...of course!  I should have figured that out on my own.  Thanks so much (and apologies for the dumb question).